# Camera API of Corona availability on Windows

Tags: camera, coronasdk, recorder

I want to make an iphone app in `corona` which uses `camera` and `audio recorder` functionality but as far as i searched out, camera app is not supported on windows OS.
So am I not able to create such app on windows environment using corona SDK and need to switch to MAC OS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being supported on windows means you cannot test on windows. If you test on the iPhone your app will work fine (if you made it correctly of course).

But you should not be developing for iOS on Windows, it is harder to debug, and you cannot upload it to apple store anyway,

Answer (score 0):

You have to be on a Mac to build for iOS devices (or use a service like MacInTheCloud).  Windows can only build for Android.  You can develop on Windows but when you need to put it on a device, you will have to have access to a Mac.